# How to Add Custom Objects in to listbox of VB 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am developing one vb application. In that I have one list box. I want to add different types of Items. Like Different Colored and differently aligned text(Like one item item is right aligned and one more is left aligned). Can you please tell me how can i do the same.

Thanks.

Comment: to do that you will need to inherit the listbox class and overload some things.. IN essence you would have to build you own custom class based on listbox.. or go buy/find a .net dll that does this. The include listbox is very basic and only some colours for global elements can be changed. not very dynamic unpleasantly

Comment: Actually I am doing a chat application. When user types something and press enter text as to display inside list box(Or any other control) with users image and other info like time and all. Is there any way I can do this. Is there any control is there instead of using ListBox?

Comment: Gridview?  you can add columns and format them the way you want. Update the application dynamically. better than listbox i suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it in one of my projects (the original code is in c#):

```
Public Class ColoringStepCommandListBox
    Inherits CommandListBox

    Const ItemHeight As Integer = 20

    Public Sub New()
        listBox.ItemHeight = ItemHeight
        listBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)
        Const  textFormatFlags__1 As TextFormatFlags = TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis Or TextFormatFlags.PreserveGraphicsClipping Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter
        Const  colorRectangleWidth As Integer = 100, textLeft As Integer = 110

        If e.Index >= 0 Then
            'Cast the listbox item to your custom type (ColoringStep in my example).
            Dim coloringStep = TryCast(listBox.Items(e.Index), ColoringStep)

            e.DrawBackground()

            'Do custom coloring and rendering, draw icons etc.
            Dim colorRect = New Rectangle(2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, colorRectangleWidth, ItemHeight - 5)
            Dim innerRect = New Rectangle(colorRect.Left + 1, colorRect.Top + 1, colorRect.Width - 1, colorRect.Height - 1)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, colorRect)
            DrawingHelper.DrawGradient(coloringStep, e.Graphics, innerRect, LinearGradientMode.Horizontal)

            'Draw the text (this does not happen automatically any more with owner draw modes).
            Dim textRect = New Rectangle(textLeft, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Width - textLeft, e.Bounds.Height)
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, coloringStep.ToString(), e.Font, textRect, e.ForeColor, textFormatFlags__1)

            e.DrawFocusRectangle()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I got simple solution for this. Below is the code

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DrawItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.DrawItem
    e.DrawBackground()
    Dim textFont As New Font(e.Font.FontFamily, e.Font.Size * 4)
    e.Graphics.DrawString(ListBox1.Items(e.Index).ToString(), textFont, New SolidBrush(Color.BlueViolet), RectangleF.op_Implicit(e.Bounds))
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub

Private Sub listBox1_MeasureItem(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MeasureItem
    e.ItemHeight = e.ItemHeight * 4
End Sub
```

You can add extra code inside ListBox1_DrawItem method to customize Items